# How to grant rights to a common user in specific pdb in a container

Tags: oracle, oracle-19c

0

I have made 4 pdbs in a container. I have one common user, and i want to give that user rights (create session etc) for a specific pdb.Any help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SQL> show con_name

CON_NAME
------------------------------
CDB$ROOT
SQL> show pdbs

    CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
         2 PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY  NO
         3 RYMIN21_PDB1                   READ WRITE NO
SQL> create user c##user1 identified by 123;

User created.

SQL> alter session set container=RYMIN21_PDB1;

Session altered.

SQL> grant create session to c##user1 container = current;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> select con_id, privilege from cdb_sys_privs where grantee = 'C##USER1';

    CON_ID PRIVILEGE
---------- ----------------------------------------
         3 CREATE SESSION

SQL> conn c##user1/123;
ERROR:
ORA-01045: user C##USER1 lacks CREATE SESSION privilege; logon denied


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
SQL> conn c##user1/123@localhost:1521/RYMIN21_PDB1
Connected.
SQL>
```